# How to detect slashes for mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am writing some mod_rewrite rules and I am a little stuck on one of them. Basically, I would like to enter the following url `pricing/packages/basic/not-for-profit` into `pricing-packages-basic-not-for-profit.php`

I think I could use

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$  $1-$2-$3-$4.php
```

Is there a way to write a rule that just automatically counts the slashes? so for example the same rule would apply for the above example and also `pricing/a-package-for-you`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work for you in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule "^([^/]+)/([^/]+/.+)$" /$1-$2 [N]
RewriteRule "^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$" /$1-$2.php [L]
```

**Explanation:**

First rule here searches if there are at least 2 slashes in the URI and if yes then first slash is converted to hyphen. This **rule is repeated** until there are at least 2 slashes in the URI. The `[N]` flag causes the ruleset to start over again from the top, using the result of the ruleset so far as a starting point.

Finally when there is one slash left then 2nd rule is executed converting slash to hyphen and adding `.php` in the end.

**UPDATE:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Sorry, I may not have explained myself well, I meant is there on function that will take care off all of the re writes regardless of the amount of slashes in the URL?

Comment: This code does exactly same i.e. no matter how many slashes are there it will convert them to hyphens.

Comment: Awesome! thank you! Would you mind explaining to me how it works please?

Comment: Sure I will add explanation in the answer.

Comment: Thank you! So if I just had /about will that work and convert it to about.php?

Comment: See UPDATE section for adding `.php` extension.